# bgstretcher is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I get error when I use bgstretcher, all links are correct to scripts, and it works on demo website, I tried to remove all other scripts from the index.php file, but still got same error - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'bgStretcher'
So here is the code -

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>STANDBY Countdown Script</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jcountdown-style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/standby-style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bgstretcher.css" />

<script src="script/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script src="script/bgstretcher.js" type="text/javscript"></script>
<script src="script/jquery.jcountdown1.3.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        //  Initialize Backgound Stretcher     
        $('body').bgStretcher({
            images: ['demo/images/sample-1.jpg', 'demo/images/sample-2.jpg', 'demo/images/sample-3.jpg', 'demo/images/sample-4.jpg', 'demo/images/sample-5.jpg', 'demo/images/sample-6.jpg'],
            imageWidth: 1024, 
            imageHeight: 768, 
            slideDirection: 'N',
            slideShowSpeed: 3000,
            transitionEffect: 'fade',
            sequenceMode: 'normal',
        });

    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#time").countdown({
        date: "January 31, 2013", /* Counting to a date */
        offset: 1,
        hoursOnly: false,
        leadingZero: true
    });

  $('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
      input.val('');
      input.removeClass('placeholder');
    }
  }).blur(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
      input.addClass('placeholder');
      input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
    }
  }).blur();    

});
</script>
</head>
```

Further there is no JS/HTML code, soI'm still not sure, what is the problem, why I get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, line 12, you misspelled javascript, which prevents the `bgstretcher.js` file from loading.  Change:

```
<script src="script/bgstretcher.js" type="text/javscript"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="script/bgstretcher.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing the comma after 'normal'

So

```
sequenceMode: 'normal',
```

becomes

```
sequenceMode: 'normal'
```